# Groovy JsonBuilder adds strange character sequences when building Json

Tags: java, json, groovy, escaping

I have an empowered enum in a Java class:
public enum FinalResponse {

```
THING_1("Thing1") {
    @Override
    String getDescription() {
        return "Based on what you've told us so far, it’s likely ; (it goes on)
    }

    @Override
    String getApplyUrl() {
        return "https://www.theinternet.com";
    }
},
```

And when I call getDescription from the following class:

```
class FinalResponseMaker {

    FinalResponseMaker() {}

    static String getResponse(FinalResponse response) {
        def output = JsonOutput.toJson([[
            code: response.getCode(),                         
            description: response.getDescription(),                             
            apply_url: response.getApplyUrl()]])
    JsonOutput.prettyPrint(output)
    }
}
```

The output from this code contains the string

```
it\u2019s likely,
```

i.e for some reason the inverted comma in "it's" has been turned into its unicode character.

Why? How can I make this stop happening?

I have tried using

```
    def pretty = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(output)
    def unescaped = JsonOutput.unescaped(pretty)
    return unescaped
```

but that doesn't work. Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the prettiest solution in the world, but ...

```
description: new String(response.getDescription().getBytes("UTF8"))
```

This should ensure that you don't get any of that escaped malarky.